# Aggregate SQL query grouping by month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database of Transactions (Access 2007) that are recorded in hourly, daily and monthly intervals.  I would like to view them in a meaningful way (instead of hour-by-hour energy usage, which is how it's stored, I want all usage for the month of January, 2011).  The tables that I want to operate on have this general format:

```
CustID|CustomerCode|TransactionDate|(Transaction Hour depending on table)|Usage
```

So If I want to take a table like that and make a view that looked something like this

```
BillingPeriod|Usage(mWh)
1/2011     |500
2/2011     |600
3/2011     |700
etc
```

How would I go about doing that?  The transaction dates can be any date, and the transaction hours can be 1-24.  The query itself doesn't seem that hard, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, SUM(Usage)
FROM UsageTable
Where (TransactionDate Between [Some Start Date] AND[Some End Date])
GROUP BY TransactionDate;
```

The problem is formatting.  I obviously can't group by transactiondate for my desired results, I just wrote it so the query was semantically correct. Maybe I could do something like

```
SELECT Mid(TransactionDate,0,2) + Mid(TransactionDate, 6, 4)?
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to group by TransactionDate BUT you have to convert the date to MM/YYYY so that your grouping works appropriately. In SQL Server this is easy to do but I noticed you are asking for ms-access so I am not sure if the same datetime functions are supported. In SQL server, you can get the month and year using the datepart function DATEPART(yyyy, TransactionDate) would get you the year and DatePart(mm,TransactionDate) will get you the month. Therefore, you could group by cast (Datepart(yyyy,TransactionDate) as varchar(4))+'-'+(Datepart(mm,TransactionDate) as varchar(2))

Comment: I just confirmed, MONTH() and YEAR() functions are supported in access

Comment: Converting values to string and then concatenating them, so as to accomplish date arithmetic, is ***Bad Practice!***  To do what you suggest just use `DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, TransactionDate), 0)`  *(Replace m with MONTH when using SQL Server, the example is the MS Access version.)*

Comment: @Dems Where is the date arithmetic you're talking about?  Are you calling GROUP BY date arithmetic?

Comment: @HansUp - Converting the Date or DateTime to a month-only value is Date Arithmetic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you would need to group by both the month and the year.  Otherwise, you'll have January 2010 and January 2011 combined:

```
SELECT YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate), SUM(Usage)
FROM YourTable
WHERE (TransactionDate Between [Some Start Date] AND[Some End Date])
GROUP BY YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(Created), MONTH(Created)
```

I don't know if your version of SQL has the MONTH and YEAR functions, so you may have to use DATEPART.

Comment: What is it with everyone trying to accomplish this with strings?  String conversion and Concatenation introduces unneccesary overheads, it can be accomplished soley using the available Date Functions.

Answer (score 4):

So as to Avoid conversion to strings, concatenations and conversion back to dates, use DATEADD() and DATEDIFF().

```
SELECT
  DATEADD("m", DATEDIFF("m", 0, TransactionDate), 0) AS TransactionMonth,
  SUM(Usage)                                         AS TotalUsage
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  TransactionDate BETWEEN <startDate> AND <endDate>
GROUP BY
  DATEADD("m", DATEDIFF("m", 0, TransactionDate), 0)
ORDER BY
  DATEADD("m", DATEDIFF("m", 0, TransactionDate), 0)
```

Comment: Both DateAdd and DateDiff require a string expression for the interval argument.  So for this approach to work, you must use quotes around the m.  Without the quotes, the db engine interprets m to be a parameter and pops up the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(TransactionDate),YEAR(TransactionDate), SUM(Usage) 
FROM UsageTable 
Where (TransactionDate Between [Some Start Date] AND[Some End Date]) 
GROUP BY MONTH(TransactionDate),YEAR(TransactionDate);
```

Comment: Same thing I did, but you remembered the WHERE clause.  I had forgotten it.

Comment: That would give me 3 columns, correct? Can I just concatenate those?

Comment: You can ! SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(TransactionDate)) + "/" + CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(TransactionDate)) Period, SUM(Usage) FROM UsageTable Where (TransactionDate Between [Some Start Date] AND[Some End Date]) GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(TransactionDate)) + "/" + CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(TransactionDate));

Comment: ARGH! :(  Please stop teaching people to convert values to and from strings, everything can be accomplished directly with the Date Functions available :(

Answer (score 1):

I generally use `Format([TransactionDate], "yyyy-mm")` because it's simple and sorts well.
As another option, you could use `[TransactionDate]-Day([TransactionDate])+1`, which will move every date to the first of its month. THe advantage is that you can still easily format that any way you want, or group that by quarter or year afterwards.

Comment: Or, you could just use the available Date Functions to avoid the overheads of converting to and from strings?

Answer (score 0):

something like...

```
SELECT Month(UsageTable.TransactionDate) & '/' & Year(UsageTable.TransactionDate) AS BillingPeriod, Sum(UsageTable.Usage) AS Usage
FROM UsageTable
WHERE (((UsageTable.TransactionDate) Between [Some Start Date] And [Some End Date]))
GROUP BY Month(UsageTable.TransactionDate) & '/' & Year(UsageTable.TransactionDate);
```

Comment: This implicitly casts values to strings, and then concatenates strings, and so introduces hidden overheads that are not necessary.  (Can be accomplished just using the available Date Functions without any string concatenation.)